# Can I extend default javascript function prototype to let some code been executed on every function call?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-proxy, javascript-proxy

Lets say there are functions

```
function a(someparams){
 console.log('a called')
}
function b(){
 console.log('b called')
}
...
const c (someParam) => { console.log('c called')}
```

I want to extend default function prototype something like
`Function.prototype.onCall = (args) => {console.log('Proxy fn called!',args)}`
in a very begining of a page code, so every existing and new functions, upon call, will log 'Proxy fn called!'.
There are solutions to map window.functions - but they only work for existing functions, and I want to extend prototype to let it execute my piece of code.
The goal is to automatically check if args are valid. No I don't want typescript or flow, thanks for suggestion.
Is this possible? where to look at?

I found

```
(function() {
    var call = Function.prototype.call;
    Function.prototype.call = function() {
        console.log(this, arguments); // Here you can do whatever actions you want
        return call.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}());
```

to be the closest to what I want so far, but these aren't called when calling a function normally, e.g. `someFunction();`, without explicit `.call` or `.apply`.

I have found maybe decorators is a way to go? the official doc said they are still not a standard https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators but there is a babel plugin https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-decorators  is it possible that it would do the job or am I looking into wrong direction?

Comment: What do you mean by the functions are not being called normally? Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: What the OP is looking for is best described with _**method modification**_. There are specialized modifiers like `around`, `before`, `after`, `afterThrowing` and `afterFinally`. In case of a search for modifier implementations one should be aware that such a modifier has to support a `thisArg` parameter in order to create a modified function which operates upon the correct `this` context (hence a method).

Comment: "Can" and "Should" differ here; probably should NOT do this IMHO.

Comment: "*Can I extend javascript […] to let some code been executed on every function call?*" - no, this is not possible. Also it would hook on the code itself that you want to execute, resulting in an infinite loop/recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Proposal**

What the OP is looking for is best described with [***method modification***](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bjavascript%5d%20%22method%20modification%22). There are specialized modifiers like [`around`](https://github.com/petsel/es-function-modifiers/blob/main/src/modifiers/around/index.js#L1), [`before`](https://github.com/petsel/es-function-modifiers/blob/main/src/modifiers/before/index.js#L1), [`after`](https://github.com/petsel/es-function-modifiers/blob/main/src/modifiers/after/index.js#L1), [`afterThrowing`](https://github.com/petsel/es-function-modifiers/blob/main/src/modifiers/afterThrowing/index.js#L1) and [`afterFinally`](https://github.com/petsel/es-function-modifiers/blob/main/src/modifiers/afterFinally/index.js#L1).

In case of a search for modifier implementations one should be aware that such **a modifier has to support a `thisArg` parameter** in order to create a modified function which operates upon the correct `this` context (hence a method).

**Answer**

There is no single point where one could implement the interception of any function's invocation, be it existing functions or the ones yet to come (e.g. functions/methods generated while an application is running).

Regardless of the possible approaches like a [***`Proxy`***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)'s [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/apply) or [`construct`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/construct) method's or ***decorators*** (as proposed by another answer) or the just mentioned ***method modifiers*** (which are specialized abstractions for otherwise more complex manual wrapping tasks), one always has to know and explicitly refer to the to be proxyfied / decorated / modified functions and methods.

**Example code** which implements and uses `Function.prototype.around` ...

```js
// 1st example ... wrapping **around** a simple function

function consumeAnyParameter(...params) {
  console.log('inside `consumeAnyParameter` ... params ...', params);
}
function interceptor(originalFunction, interceptorReference, ...params) {
  // intercept.
  console.log('inside `interceptor` ... ', {
    params,
    originalFunction,
    interceptorReference,
  });
  // proceed.
  originalFunction(...params);
}

// reassignment of ... a modified version of itself.
consumeAnyParameter = consumeAnyParameter.around(interceptor);

// invoke modified version.
consumeAnyParameter('foo', 'bar', 'baz');


// 2nd example ... wrapping **around** a type's method.

const type = {
  foo: 'foo',
  bar: 'bar',
  whoAmI: function () {
    console.log('Who am I? I\'m `this` ...', this);
  }
}
type.whoAmI();

type.whoAmI = type
  .whoAmI
  .around(function (proceed, interceptor, ...params) {

    console.log('interceptor\'s `this` context ...', this);
    console.log('interceptor\'s `params` ...', params);

    // proceed.apply(this, params);
    proceed.call(this);

  }, type); // for method modification do pass the context/target. 

type.whoAmI();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>
// poor man's module.
(function (Function) {

  // module scope.

  function getSanitizedTarget(value) {
    return value ?? null;
  }
  function isFunction(value) {
    return (
      'function' === typeof value &&
      'function' === typeof value.call &&
      'function' === typeof value.apply
    );
  }

  // modifier implementation.

  function around/*Modifier*/(handler, target) {
    target = getSanitizedTarget(target);

    const proceed = this;

    return (
      isFunction(handler) &&
      isFunction(proceed) &&

      function aroundType(...argumentArray) {
        // the target/context of the initial modifier/modification time
        // still can be overruled by a handler's apply/call time context.
        const context = getSanitizedTarget(this) ?? target;

        return handler.call(
          context,
          proceed,
          handler,
          argumentArray,
        );
      }
    ) || proceed;
  }

  // modifier assignment.

  Object.defineProperty(Function.prototype, 'around', {
    configurable: true,
    writable: true,
    value: around/*Modifier*/,
  });

}(Function));
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but looks like with this I'll need to explicitly point out which functions to attach .around to. I was lookin into kind of prototype modification to be made in a way that proxy function would be called automatically, even for anonymous functions, for arrow functions, or when new functions created. My reason for this I'd like to implement my own, custom, optionl real-time parameters&return value typecheck for js functions, but dont want to convert to pseudo-language like TypeScript untill (if) they will be natively supported->debuggable

Comment: @KatyC ... (OP) _"I was lookin into kind of prototype modification to be made this way that proxy function would be called automatically, even for anonymous functions, for arrow functions, or when new functions created"_ ... As **Bergi** already said ... _"no, this is not possible. **Also it would hook on the code itself that you want to execute**, resulting in an infinite loop/recursion. "_ ... (OP) _"Looks like I'll need to explicitly point out which functions to attach .around to"_ ... Exactly, but this could be automated to a big extend as well.

Comment: To solve the infinite loop problem, I suppose one could check if Function#caller is equal to Function#call.